# Error in Azure Storage Explorer "Cannot read property 'accessTier' of undefined". What could be causing it?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

As the title says. I am using Azure Storage Explorer to store some blobs. There is a mix of objects on the hot, cool and archive tier there. My current task requires me to move or copy files around in the container. I get this error during such operations and the application view resets to show the storage account view rather than the container view.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error? I'd appreciate any help. Thank you.

[image: screenshot of Azure storage explorer error]

Comment: What's the kind (General Purpose V1, V2 etc.) of the storage account on which you're trying to perform this operation?

Comment: This is general Storage V2. Azure admin has created a subscription and given me access to the portal via that subscription, using Azure AD. I created the storage account and blob container. Thank you

Comment: Interestingly I am not able to reproduce the error in the portal web view of storage explorer.

The error occurs when :
- I am in the desktop version of the application
- I am in a folder that has a mix of files in various access tiers (hot, cool and archive)
- I click on the "Access Tier" column heading to sort the files by what access tier they are in
- Error appears on the top of the screen and the view resets to the storage account level rather than the blob level.